# How do I instantiate FileIntegrityManager in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I instantiate [FileIntegrityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/FileIntegrityManager) in Android?

Language: Kotlin
Android Studio HedgeHog | 2023.1.1 (Nov 2023)
TargetSDK 33

```
val foo = FileIntegrityManager()// Compile Error:  Error message says init is private so you cannot access it.
```

I checked another initializer in FileIntegrityManager's declared file, but it looks like developers cannot access it. How do you initialize this class?

Somehow I should instantiate FileIntegrityManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not create an instance yourself. Instead, call `getSystemService(FileIntegrityManager::class.java)` on a `Context` to get a `FileIntegrityManager` instance.

In theory, you could also pass [`FILE_INTEGRITY_SERVICE` to `getSystemService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context?hl=en#FILE_INTEGRITY_SERVICE).

Comment: I am able to instantiate the class with your suggestion. Thank you very much!